# Build ARIMA model equation with exogenous variable or regressors

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a ARIMA model with three regressors as follow

```
> fit_arima.reg
Series: sales.ts 
Regression with ARIMA(5,1,3) errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3      ar4      ar5      ma1     ma2
      0.1806  -0.7205  -0.2697  -0.3786  -0.4372  -0.8307  0.5047
s.e.  0.0786   0.0521   0.0614   0.0277   0.0469   0.0849  0.0920
          ma3  pholid  sholid     temp
      -0.1397  0.0413  0.1192  -0.0015
s.e.   0.0662  0.0313  0.0180   0.0015

sigma^2 estimated as 0.02461:  log likelihood=412.15
AIC=-800.3   AICc=-799.96   BIC=-742.11
```

The data is posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425187/build-sarima-model-equation-with-exogenous-variable-or-regressors?noredirect=1#comment794121_425187) (only the values of two independent variables are missing) and I also referred four links of previous posts related to this topic. I built the equation, but the fitted values by hand (from equation) and the ones generated by R do not match. I would appreciate your help for the solution.
This is what I did:

```
fitted <-fit_arima.reg$x - (fit_arima.reg$coef["pholid"]*xregg$pholid) - (fit_arima.reg$coef["sholid"]*xregg$sholid) - (fit_arima.reg$coef["temp"]*xregg$temp)

detach("package:dplyr", unload=T)
library(tsDyn)
lag1.fit <- lag(fitted,-1)
lag2.fit <- lag(fitted,-2)
lag3.fit <- lag(fitted,-3)
lag4.fit <- lag(fitted,-4)
lag5.fit <- lag(fitted,-5)
lag6.fit <- lag(fitted,-6)

residuals <- fit_arima.reg$x-fitted # are those the residuals?

lag1.res <- lag(residuals,-1)
lag2.res <- lag(residuals,-2)
lag3.res <- lag(residuals,-3)

fitted_equation <-  fit_arima.reg$coef["pholid"]*xregg$pholid+
  fit_arima.reg$coef["sholid"]*xregg$sholid+ 
  fit_arima.reg$coef["temp"]*xregg$temp+
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar1"]*lag1.fit+
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar2"]*lag2.fit+
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar3"]*lag3.fit+
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar4"]*lag4.fit+
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar5"]*lag5.fit+
  lag1.fit-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar1"]*lag2.fit-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar2"]*lag3.fit-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar3"]*lag4.fit-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar4"]*lag5.fit-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ar5"]*lag6.fit-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ma1"]*lag1.res-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ma2"]*lag2.res-
  fit_arima.reg$coef["ma3"]*lag3.res

> tail(cbind(fitted_equation,fit_arima.reg$fitted))
Time Series:
Start = c(2019, 210) 
End = c(2019, 215) 
Frequency = 365 
     fitted_equation fit_arima.reg$fitted
2019.573        3.469460             3.426007
2019.575        3.833233             3.623222
2019.578        3.309229             3.507476
2019.581        3.617242             3.418212
2019.584        3.067797             3.196589
2019.586        3.195247                   NA
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Similar to [Build SARIMA model equation with exogenous variable or regressors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425187/build-sarima-model-equation-with-exogenous-variable-or-regressors/425349?noredirect=1#comment794205_425349)  . you have the following equation [image] which leads to this after clearing fractions .. multiplying out etc ...

[image]

Note that by ordinary convention the ma coefficients are presented differently than what you have seen with your references BUT the answers would be the same.

The data I used had 200 historical observations BUT that doesn't change the way the coefficients are re-presented in a "regression type form " and without the often ( to some !) confusing polynomials and differencing operators.

Comment: Thank very much for your constant feedback and help!